# how index unpublished node in drupal apache solr

Tags: drupal, solr, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am using apache solr module in drupal 7. I have to index unpublished node.

But drupal apache solr module only index published node.

Is there is any patch for index unpublished node?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to follow this thread: [Index unpublished nodes](http://drupal.org/node/632282). There is no available patch right now but you'll find some hints to build your own custom module if you need to.